# Execute fill command relative to player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I execute the fill command relative to the player? If you are wondering why I am asking this, and for more information, reference my earlier question here: [How to make a block disappear after a certain period of time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168809/how-to-make-a-block-disappear-after-a-certain-period-of-time) Look to the bottom section for the info you want. Also, I don't want it to just fill the selected areas, I just want to replace wool with air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`/execute <selector> ~ ~ ~ fill <relative coordinates> air 0 replace wool`

[EDIT]

If you are wanting the block to disappear after a certain amount of time, say, 30 redstone ticks (60 game ticks), you could summon a `WitherSkull` below the player and use the execute command on it.

To make the block disappear, you would add a new scoreboard command, `lifetime`, for instance, and run `/scoreboard players add @e[type=WitherSkull] lifetime 1` with a setblock or fill clock, then execute another fill command on every wither skull with a certain lifetime value, like:

`/execute @e[type=WitherSkull,score_lifetime_min=31] ~ ~ ~ /fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ wool 0 replace air`.

Then, you would kill the wither skull: `/kill @e[type=WitherSkull,score_lifetime_min=35]`.

Here is a screenshot of what I did:

[image: Adding the ability to walk on blocks.]

Comment: What do you mean by 'relative coordinates'? Could you give an example?

Comment: In this case, as I am assuming you want blocks to be placed _under_ the player, you would do `~ ~-1 ~`.

Comment: Actually I wanted to make a 7x7x7 hollow "cube", but I already figured out how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
/execute at @p positioned ~ ~ ~ run fill ~-5 ~-2 ~-5 ~5 ~2 ~5 minecraft:air replace minecraft:wool
```

Here's the new command for Java, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

To fill an area relative to the player, put the following code into a command block or your chat: `/execute @<p,a,r,e> <x> <y> <z> /fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> 0 replace <blocktoreplace>`. The p, a, r, and e are the selectors.

- `@p` is as if you had typed the nearest players name in
- `@a` is as if you had put everyone's name tag in
- `@r` is as if you had put a random player's name in, and
- `@e` is as if you had put every entity's ID in.

The first x, y, and z are the **relative** coordinates, meaning that they must have the symbol `~` before them, and are relative to the player. The next two sets of x y and z  should also be relative otherwise there wouldn't be any use of using execute. The block is now used by it's name with `minecraft:` before it or what ever mod it comes from with a colon after meaning that items that have the same name won't override each other. The block to replace is just that, the block to replace.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone reading this in the future like I was, `/execute [selector]` doesn't work anymore. If you want to execute at someone's location, use `/execute AT [selector]` and then the relative `~ ~ ~` or modified relative `~ ~-5 ~` and the like coords.