# Clearing out large areas with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What command would you use to clear out a large area relative to the player that doesn't go down but up? I've tried one but it would clear the stone down to bedrock. Also is there a way to make it clear everything rather than just stone?

The command I've tried is

```
/execute at @p positioned ~ ~ ~ run fill ~-5 ~-1 ~-5 -5 -1 -5 minecraft:air replace minecraft:stone
```

I've been messing with it trying to get it to work.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to respond. The command I've tried is /execute at @p positioned ~ ~ ~ run fill ~-5 ~-1 ~-5 -5 -1 -5 minecraft:air replace minecraft:stone, and I've been messing woth it trying to get it to work. I'm not every good at commands so it's hard for me.

Comment: I think you are specifying the second group of coords in the wrong way. Try to write all of them in the ~x format.

Comment: Can you specify a little more? Im not familiar with commands like AT all. Im more of the survival/building type of person, ive never really experimented like this before.

Answer (score 3):

Fill command has this syntax:

```
/fill <from> <to> <block> replace <newBlock>
```

"from" and "to" coordinates need to be specified using relative world coordinates (~ notation, it's an offset from a defined position) or world coordinates (the exact world numbers).

Suppose you want to replace only stone with air in a 10x10x10 cube with the base centered in the player (starting from `~-5 ~0 ~-5` and ending in `~5 ~10 ~5`), the final command will be:

```
/fill ~-5 ~0 ~-5 ~5 ~10 ~5 minecraft:air replace minecraft:stone
```

If you want to destroy everything in that space, no matter what the blocks are, then just write

```
/fill ~-5 ~0 ~-5 ~5 ~10 ~5 minecraft:air destroy
```

this will also drop every block like they were mined by a pickaxe.

To put grass under you the command is

```
/fill ~-5 ~-1 ~-5 ~5 ~-1 ~5 minecraft:grass_block destroy
```

If you want to clear everything upwards in a defined area, just set a Y-coord that reaches the upper limit, which (from 1.18 version) is 320.

**EDIT**:

If you don't want the command to be centered in the block position and make it follow you, just try:

```
/execute at @p run fill ~-5 ~0 ~-5 ~5 ~10 ~5 minecraft:air destroy
```

You may need to set it as a repeating command.

See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168841/execute-fill-command-relative-to-player) for more information about fill command.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are the GOAT

Comment: You're welcome! If that was useful please consider accepting the answer with the green tick :)

Comment: Hey so i finally was able to test it out, and its centering the break around the command block. It also breaks the command block too.

Comment: Also what would i use in a command block to also make the blocks under my feet grass

Comment: i wanted to use the command block to replace the blocks around me repeatedly

Comment: Will this work with the grass command as well (I mean the configuration)

Comment: The command isnt working, i have no idea why

Comment: @MrMonmer I've updated the command