# How to make blocks appear under your feet when you walk/jump?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there anyway to make blocks appear under your feet wherever you walk or jump? I there a way to make them disappear after like 20 seconds?

Comment: I noticed this is kind of a duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168809/how-to-make-a-block-disappear-after-a-certain-period-of-time?rq=1 except I need it in bedrock edition.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this answer assumes you would want this to be active constantly.*

---

Use `\execute @e[type=player] ~~~ setblock ~~-1~ <block>`
Replace `<block>` with a block of your choice.

Comment: Can I turn it off with a switch on a command block?

Comment: And is their any way to make the blocks disappear after like 10-20 seconds?

Comment: > Can I turn it off with a switch on a command block? Yes, you can by enabling the “needs red stone” option and placing a lever on the command block.

Comment: As for your other question… I don’t know.